# Why does allocating a GstBuffer inside a function cause gst_buffer_add_meta to fail as the buffer isn't writable?

Tags: c, gstreamer

I'm writing some unit tests to test a GStreamer element I've written and I've come across a strange case I can't explain/fix.

If I allocated a buffer as below it works; it's allocated and I can pass it to other functions to write meta data

```
GstBuffer *crop1_buf = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, 1920 * 1080 * 3, NULL);
```

If I make a simple function

```
void allocate_buffer(GstBuffer *buf)
{
    buf = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, 1920 * 1080 * 3, NULL);
}
```

and then where I'd previously allocated my buffer I instead do:

```
GstBuffer *crop1_buf;
allocate_buffer(crop1_buf);
```

I get `Unexpected critical/warning: gst_buffer_add_meta: assertion 'gst_buffer_is_writable (buffer)' failed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to modify the pointer itself, so you need to pass the pointer to it

```
void allocate_buffer(GstBuffer **buf)
{
    *buf = gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, 1920 * 1080 * 3, NULL);
}
```

and example usage:

```
GstBuffer *mybyff;

allocate_buffer(&mybuff);
```